# How to show the End-User License Agreement ("EULA") in the license agreement screen based on the language or locale using NSIS

Tags: nsis

How to show the End-User License Agreement ("EULA") in the license agreement screen based on the language or locale.

Below is the line of code to show the license agreement in the License Agreement screen. But it is showing only in English.

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Docs\Modern UI\license.rtf"
```

I placed all other language license.rtf files in a common folder. And then when i am trying to write

```
${If} $Language == 1033
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Docs\Modern UI\license.rtf"
  ${EndIf}
```

It is showing the compilation error "Error: command StrCmp not valid outside Section or Function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MUI documentation tells you what to do:

> For a license text in multiple languages, `LicenseLangString` can be used. Refer the NSIS Users Manual for more information about installers with multiple languages.

And the NSIS Users Manual says:

> `LicenseLangString license ${LANG_ENGLISH} license-english.txt`
>
> `LicenseLangString license ${LANG_FRENCH} license-french.txt`
>
> `LicenseLangString license ${LANG_GERMAN} license-german.txt`
>
> `LicenseData $(license)`

For MUI you just point the MUI license page to your LicenseLangString:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE $(translatedlicensefile)
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
LicenseLangString translatedlicensefile ${LANG_ENGLISH} "lic-eng.txt"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE Swedish
LicenseLangString translatedlicensefile ${LANG_SWEDISH} "lic-swe.txt"
```